# Is there a good way to convert from a WIM file to an ESD file other than using Dism?

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, dism, wim, esd

Some background info first - My friend and I are trying to create a "local deployment tool" in batch that allows us to capture an image of a sysprepped computer and export it into a pre-existing windows install disk. The idea is that we want to be able to have our own images pop up in the windows install disk, rather than the standard Windows 10 images. We're working with Windows 10 right now.

Our research suggested that there was no way to do this besides using Dism to capture WIM images and export them to replace the existing install.esd image already in the Windows install disk. However, the compression as the WIM exports into an ESD is incredibly taxing, so I was trying to find a way to avoid that. Maybe I could just point the installer to an install.wim, or find a way to compress it so it isn't such a problem? I'm happy that it works, but for our purposes, we need it to be faster and less demanding.

Long story short, does anyone know of any alternatives to what we're doing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: use WIM format all the time, is better that ESD

Comment: @magicandre1981 does WIM work with the windows install disk, though? Would I have to somehow point it towards install.wim files instead of install.esd ones, or can I just smack it right in and call it a day?

EDIT: typo

Comment: WIM was the original format for Windows setup since Vista. ESD is encrypted version which makes it more difficult to manage the ESD (add updates, drivers)